# Updating View in ViewModel

Tags: c#, data-binding, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

Let's say I have a property that is binded to a TextBlock. Let's say the binding looks something like this:

```
public string Data
{
     get { return _text; }
     set
     { 
          _text = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("Data");
     }        
}
```

Somewhere else in my code if I say `Data = "blue";` why do I have to say `OnPropertyChanged("Text");` again? It won't update automatically if I don't add the OnPropertyChanged a second time. I thought that since I'm doing the OnPropertyChanged in the set accessor it would update the view automatically when I assign something to the property?

Comment: Have you put a break point in the set accessor to verify that code is running when you do `.Data = "blue";` Might not be the same class you think it is.

Comment: What? the property name `Data` and the property name in the `OnPropertyChanged()` do not match. I don't understand what you're doing here. What's the XAML bound to? `Data` or `Text`??

Comment: @AaronLS they are in the same class.

Comment: @HighCore See above edit. Sorry about that, I made the code up on the spot. That's not the actual code I'm using. The XAML is bound to Data.

Comment: Use same names for property and backingfields: Data and _data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was doing `_text = "Blue";` instead of `Data = "Blue";` Once I changed it to assign the text to the property instead of the field the View was updated correctly.